# Regex to match violations if a special word is found

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex which does the following:

```
//SPECIAL_WORD some text -> Should match

//SPECIAL_WORD (123456) -> Should match

//SPECIAL_WORD 123456   -> Should NOT match
```

=> Basically anything other then 'SPECIAL_WORD blank 6 digits' should match if the SPECIAL_WORD is found.

I found how I can match the positive case `SPECIAL_WORD\s\d{6}`
I tried the positive lookahead however didn't get it to work: `(?!SPECIAL_WORD\s\d{6})`. I also tried to negate the whole thing `\b(?=\w)(?!SPECIAL_WORD\s\d{6})\b(\w*)`however then everything else is matched...
Any ideas?

Comment: You are almost near `\bTODO\s(?!\d{6}\b)`

Comment: In order to validate you need to define what `some text` actually is. We know it's not 6 digits. But, not 6 digits opens up a _universe_ of what is valid. Is the _universe_ acceptable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match `SPECIAL_WORD` then go for a negative lookahead:

```
\bSPECIAL_WORD\s(?!\d{6}\b)
```

`\b` assures that both ends are not part of a word. You may not need them.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/2xzt83/1)

Comment: Perfect that works, thanks! Regex is needed so often but sometimes it is still a mystery :-)